# How to create a sentence out of my Clarifai Extracted Features?

Tags: javascript, html, clarifai

I am working on Clarifai API to extract features of an image which is done successfully. But I want to the extracted the features to be adjusted in a sentence. for example if from a picture the extracted words are furniture, room, bed the sentence should be constructed such as This is a room of furniture and bed is inside the room.

```js
/*
  Purpose: Pass information to other helper functions after a user clicks 'Predict'
  Args:
    value - Actual filename or URL
    source - 'url' or 'file'
*/
function predict_click(value, source) {
  // first grab current index
  var index = document.getElementById("hidden-counter").value;

  // Div Stuff
  if(index > 1) {
    createNewDisplayDiv(index);
  }
  
  if(source === "url") {
    document.getElementById("img_preview" + index).src = value;
    doPredict({ url: value });
    
    // Div Stuff
    createHiddenDivs("url", value);
  }
    
  else if(source === "file") {
    var preview = document.querySelector("#img_preview" + index);
    var file    = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    // load local file picture
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      preview.src = reader.result;
      var localBase64 = reader.result.split("base64,")[1];
      doPredict({ base64: localBase64 });


      
      // Div Stuff
      createHiddenDivs("base64", localBase64);
        
    }, false);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  } 
}

/*
  Purpose: Does a v2 prediction based on user input
  Args:
    value - Either {url : urlValue} or { base64 : base64Value }
*/
function doPredict(value) {

  var modelID = getSelectedModel();

  app.models.predict(modelID, value).then(
    
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      var conceptNames = "";
      var tagArray, regionArray;
      var tagCount = 0;
      var modelName = response.rawData.outputs[0].model.name;
      var modelNameShort = modelName.split("-")[0];
      var modelHeader = '<b><span style="font-size:14px">' + capitalize(modelNameShort) + ' Model</span></b>';
      
      // Check for regions models first
      if(response.rawData.outputs[0].data.hasOwnProperty("regions")) {
        regionArray = response.rawData.outputs[0].data.regions;
       
        // Regions are found, so iterate through all of them
        for(var i = 0; i < regionArray.length; i++) {
         conceptNames += "<b>Result " + (i+1) + "</b>";  
           
         // Demographic has separate sub-arrays
         if(modelName == "demographics") {
           var ageArray = regionArray[i].data.face.age_appearance.concepts;
           var ethnicArray = regionArray[i].data.face.multicultural_appearance.concepts;
           var genderArray = regionArray[i].data.face.gender_appearance.concepts;
          
            // Age Header
           conceptNames += '<br/><b><span style="font-size:10px">Age Appearance</span></b>';
        
           // print top 5 ages
           for(var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
             conceptNames += '<li>' + ageArray[a].name + ': <i>' + ageArray[a].value + '</i></li>';
            }
        
           // Ethnicity Header
           conceptNames += '<b><span style="font-size:10px">Multicultural Appearance</span></b>';
         
           // print top 3 ethnicities
           for(var e = 0; e < 3; e++) {
             conceptNames += '<li>' + ethnicArray[e].name + ': <i>' + ethnicArray[e].value + '</i></li>';
            }
            
           // Gender Header
           conceptNames += '<b><span style="font-size:10px">Gender Appearance</span></b>';
        
           // print gender
           conceptNames += '<li>' + genderArray[0].name + ': <i>' + genderArray[0].value + '</i></li>';
       }
        
        // For faces just print bounding boxes
       else if(modelName == "face-v1.3") {
         // Top Row
         conceptNames += '<li>Top Row: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.top_row + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Left Column: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.left_col + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Bottom Row: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.bottom_row + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Right Column: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.right_col + '</i></li>';
       }
        
       // Celebrity
       else if(modelName == "celeb-v1.3") {
         tagArray = regionArray[i].data.face.identity.concepts;
         
         // Print first 10 results
         for(var c=0; c < 10; c++) {
           conceptNames += '<li>' + tagArray[c].name + ': <i>' + tagArray[c].value + '</i></li>'; 
          }
       }
        
       // Logos
       else if(modelName == "logo") {
         // Print all results
         conceptNames += '<br/><b><span style="font-size:10px">Logo</span></b>';
         conceptNames += '<li>' + regionArray[i].data.concepts[0].name + ': <i>' + regionArray[i].data.concepts[0].value + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<br/><b><span style="font-size:10px">Location</span></b>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Top Row: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.top_row + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Left Column: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.left_col + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Bottom Row: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.bottom_row + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Right Column: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.right_col + '</i></li>';
       }
        
       // Focus
       else if(modelName == "focus") {
         // Print total focus score and all regions with focus
         conceptNames += '<br/><b><span style="font-size:10px">Focus Region</span></b>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Top Row: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.top_row + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Left Column: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.left_col + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Bottom Row: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.bottom_row + '</i></li>';
         conceptNames += '<li>Right Column: <i>' + regionArray[i].region_info.bounding_box.right_col + '</i></li>';
          
          if(i === regionArray.length - 1) {
          conceptNames += '<br><br><li><br><br>Overall Focus: <i>' + response.rawData.outputs[0].data.focus.value + '</i><br><br><br></li>'; 
        }
       }

       tagCount+=10;       
      }
     }
      
      // Color Model
      else if(modelName === "color") {
       conceptNames += '<b><span style="font-size:10px">Colors</span></b>';
        tagArray = response.rawData.outputs[0].data.colors;
        
        for (var col = 0; col < tagArray.length; col++) {
          conceptNames += '<li>' + tagArray[col].w3c.name + ': <i>' + tagArray[col].value + '</i></li>';
        }
        
        tagCount=tagArray.length;
      }
      
      // Generic tag response models
      else if(response.rawData.outputs[0].data.hasOwnProperty("concepts")) {
        tagArray = response.rawData.outputs[0].data.concepts;
        
        for (var other = 0; other < tagArray.length; other++) {
          conceptNames += '<li>' + tagArray[other].name + ': <i>' + tagArray[other].value + '</i></li>';
        }
        
        tagCount=tagArray.length;
      }
      
      // Bad region request
      else {
       if(modelName != "logo" && modelName != "focus") {
          $('#concepts').html("<br/><br/><b>No Faces Detected!</b>");
        }
       else if(modelName == "logo") {
          $('#concepts').html("<br/><br/><b>No Logos Detected!</b>");
        }
        else {
          $('#concepts').html("<br/><br/><b>No Focus Regions Detected!</b>");
        }
       return;
      }
      
      var columnCount = tagCount / 10;
      
      // Focus gets one more column
      if(modelName == "focus") {
       columnCount += 1;
      }
      
      conceptNames = '<ul style="margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px; columns:' + columnCount + '; -webkit-columns:' + columnCount + '; -moz-columns:' + columnCount + ';">' + conceptNames;
        
      conceptNames += '</ul>';
      conceptNames = modelHeader + conceptNames;
      
      $('#concepts').html(conceptNames);
      
      document.getElementById("add-image-button").style.visibility = "visible";
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}

/*
  Purpose: Return a back-end model id based on current user selection
  Returns:
    Back-end model id
*/
function getSelectedModel() {
  var model = document.querySelector('input[name = "model"]:checked').value;
  
  if(model === "general") {
    return Clarifai.GENERAL_MODEL;
  }
    
  else if(model === "food") {
    return Clarifai.FOOD_MODEL;
  }
    
  else if(model === "NSFW") {
    return Clarifai.NSFW_MODEL;
  }
    
  else if(model === "travel") {
    return Clarifai.TRAVEL_MODEL;
  }
    
  else if(model === "wedding") {
    return Clarifai.WEDDINGS_MODEL;
  }
    
  else if(model === "color") {
    return Clarifai.COLOR_MODEL;
  }
  
  else if(model === "demographic") {
    return Clarifai.DEMOGRAPHICS_MODEL;
  }
  
  else if(model === "logo") {
    return Clarifai.LOGO_MODEL;
  }
  
  else if(model === "apparel") {
    return "e0be3b9d6a454f0493ac3a30784001ff";
  }
  
  else if(model === "faces") {
    return Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL;
  }
  
  else if(model == "focus") {
    return Clarifai.FOCUS_MODEL;
  }
  
  else if(model === "celebrity") {
    return "e466caa0619f444ab97497640cefc4dc";
  }
  
  else if(model === "moderation") {
    return "d16f390eb32cad478c7ae150069bd2c6";
  }
  
  else if(model === "portrait") {
    return "de9bd05cfdbf4534af151beb2a5d0953";
  }
  
  else if(model === "landscape") {
    return "bec14810deb94c40a05f1f0eb3c91403";
  }
  
  else if(model == "texturespatterns") {
    return "fbefb47f9fdb410e8ce14f24f54b47ff";
  }
  
  else if(model === "custom") {
    var e = document.getElementById("custom_models_dropdown");
    return e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  }
}

/*
  Purpose: Add an image to an application after user clicks button
  Args:
    index - # of the image in the session
*/
function addImageToApp(index) {
  var imgType = document.getElementById("hidden-type" + index).value;
  var imgValue = document.getElementById("hidden-val" + index).value;
  
  if(imgType === "url") {
    app.inputs.create({
      url: imgValue
    }).then(
      function(response) {
        alert("Image successfully added!");
      },
      function(err) {
        alert("Error Adding Image. Check to see if it is a duplicate.");
      }
    );
  }
  
  else if(imgType === "base64") {
    app.inputs.create({
      base64: imgValue
    }).then(
      function(response) {
        alert("Image successfully added!");
      },
      function(err) {
        alert("Error Adding Image. Check to see if it is a duplicate.");
      }
    );
  }
}

/*
  Purpose: Create a dynamic div to store entire user session
  Args:
    index - # of the image in the session
*/
function createNewDisplayDiv(index) {
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("predictions");
  
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = 
    '<div style="margin-top:30px; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:30px; clear:left; float:left"> \
      <img id="img_preview' + index + '" src="" width="400"/> \
      <br/> \
      <span id="add-image-button" style="visibility:hidden"> \
        <button onClick="addImageToApp(' + index + ')">Add image to application</button> \
      </span> \
    </div> \
    <div id="concepts" class="conceptBox"> \
    </div>';
    
  mainDiv.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + mainDiv.innerHTML;
}

/*
  Purpose: Creates hidden Div elements to store info of each picture uploaded
  Args:
    urlOrBase64 - binary variable to store the type of image
    source - the actual URL string or the base64
*/
function createHiddenDivs(urlOrBase64, source) {
  // first grab current index
  var index = document.getElementById("hidden-counter").value;
  
  // type
  var input1 = document.createElement("input");
  input1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input1.setAttribute("id", "hidden-type"+index);
  input1.setAttribute("name", "hidden-type"+index);
  input1.setAttribute("value", urlOrBase64);
  
  // value
  var input2 = document.createElement("input");
  input2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input2.setAttribute("id", "hidden-val"+index);
  input2.setAttribute("name", "hidden-val"+index);
  input2.setAttribute("value", source);
  
  // add new inputs to page
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(input1);
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(input2);
  
  // increment index
  document.getElementById("hidden-counter").value = parseInt(index)+1;
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(input1.document);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

}

/*
  Purpose: Return a capitalized String
  Args:
    s - A String
*/
function capitalize(s)
{

  return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script> 
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") { 
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
      setTimeout(function() { 
         responsiveVoice.cancel(); 
         responsiveVoice.speak(getSelectionText());
      }, 1);
   });
});
</script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Clarifai JavaScript Stater</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="predict.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="keys.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sdk.clarifai.com/js/clarifai-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
  try {
    var app = new Clarifai.App({
     apiKey: myApiKey
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    alert("Need a valid API Key!");
    throw "Invalid API Key";
  }
  
  // Checks for valid image type
  function validFile(imageName) {
    var lowerImageName = imageName.toLowerCase();
    return lowerImageName.search(/jpg|png|bmp|tiff/gi) != -1;
  }
  
  // Fills custom model dropdown
  window.onload = function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("custom_models_dropdown");
    
    app.models.list().then(
      function(response) {
        var ids = response.rawData;
        
        for(var i=0; i < ids.length; i++) {
          var model = ids[i];
          if(model.app_id != "main") {
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = model.name;
            el.value = model.id;
            select.appendChild(el);
          }
        }
      },
      function(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    );
  }
  </script>
  
 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Title" style="font-size:48px; font-face:Arial; margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="Clarifai_Logo.png" id="logo"/>&nbsp;Model Tester!</div>
  <div id="Model_Title" style="font-size:16px; margin-bottom:5px">Model</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-counter" name="hidden-counter" value="1"/>
  <form action="" style="font-size:14px; margin-bottom:20px; float:left; margin-right:30px;">
    <input type="radio" name="model" value="general" checked="checked"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <div style="float:left">
    <button onclick="
      if(imgurl.value == '') {
        alert('Please enter an image URL!');
        return;
      }

      else if (!validFile(imgurl.value)) {
        alert('Supported File Types: JPEG, PNG, TIFF, BMP');
        return;
      }

      predict_click($('#imgurl').val(), 'url');" style="width:112px">Predict a URL!</button>

    <input type="text" id="imgurl" placeholder="Image URL" size="80"/>
    
    <br/><br/>
    
    <button onclick="
      if(filename.value == '') { 
        alert('Please browse for a file!'); 
        return;
      } 
    
      else if (!validFile(filename.value)) {
        alert('Supported File Types: JPEG, PNG, TIFF, BMP');
        return;
      }
      predict_click($('#filename').val(), 'file');">Predict a local file!</button>
    
    <input type="file" id="filename" placeholder="Filename" size="80"/>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="predictions">
    <div style="margin-top:30px; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:30px; clear:left; float:left">
      <img id="img_preview1" src="" width="400"/>
      <br/>
      <span id="add-image-button" style="visibility:hidden"><button onClick="addImageToApp(1)">Add image to application</button></span>
    </div>
    <div id="concepts" class="conceptBox">
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Clarifai API does not provide a service of assembling the words into sentences. You'll have to use some other service that would do that. [Here's a project](https://github.com/andykamath/Caption-Generator) that has done that and might interest you.